# Div becomes child of previous div? - a quirk of CSS? Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser

It's working this way on all the browsers I can see the page from. I swear to you that this is the *exact* code from the html:

```
<td class="bardisplay">
  <div class="bar hot" />
  <div class="bar cool" />
</td>
```

But yet in the debugger of every single browser I've brought this up in, the DOM inspector shows something like this: (Chrome, here)

[image]

There is no difference between Mozilla, IE, and Chrome. I about freaked out when I saw it in the Chrome debugger.

Here is all the pertinent CSS:

```
  td.bardisplay { 
      height      : 66px;
      padding     : 8px 0px;
      margin-left : 5pt;
  }

  .bar { height  : 50px; }
  .hot { 
    float            : left;
    background-color : red;
  }
  .cool {  
    float            : left;
    background-color : green; 
  }
```

Now, the really weird thing: I did not have this problem, with the *same html* when I put all my bar displays into a main table (3 levels up).

I had a six-column table, one with a label, one with a display, and one with a ratio, and the next three repeating, but I did not like how the second set of columns would "wag" back and forth as the table was updated. So I set the master table to a single row of two tds with three-column tables inside them. The display is now rock-solid, except that the DOM wants to put one div inside the other.

I googled this about every way I could think before posting here.

Comment: Divs aren't self-closing.

Comment: @Quentin, if you call using the wrong slash to close an element "the same question", _yeah_, I guess it has.

Answer (score 3):

`<div>`'s **cannot** self-close, so the browser assumes the second one is the child of the first one:

```
<td class="bardisplay">
  <div class="bar hot"></div>
  <div class="bar cool"></div>
</td>
```

> In HTML 5, `<foo />` means `<foo>`, the start tag. It is not a "self-closing tag". Instead, certain elements are designated as having no end tag, for example `<br>`. These are collectively called void elements. The slash is just syntactic sugar for people who are addicted to XML. Using the slash in a non-void element tag is invalid, but browsers parse it as the start tag anyway, leading to a mismatch in end tags.

<sup>[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3558200/3285730)</sup>

Comment: Okay, that's weird. Because, I did change it _from_ `<div...></div>` when I rewrote the table, and I thought I went through, and did a global replace and changed it back with no improvement. In what I've read about HTML 5, I didn't know that they were going *away* from XML, though. That's handy to know.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
<td class="bardisplay">
    <div class="bar hot"> </div>
    <div class="bar cool"> </div>
</td>
```